# Vuetify Datatable - Rendering element on first row only

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i have a problem on a vue project of mine.
i have a vuetify datatable that receives data from a .net core backend with mongo.
it works just fine and every row have a edit and delete buttons. but in this case i need to limit  edit and delete buttons to show only on the first row of the datatable.

i've tried a lot of solutions from the internet but none of them worked for me so far.

here's the code for the datatable and the buttons, respectively:

```
 <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="pacientes"
        :search="search"
        :page.sync="page"
        :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
        hide-default-footer
        sort-by="status"
        class="elevation-1"
        @page-count="pageCount = $event"
      >
<template
          v-slot:item.edit="{ item }" >
          <v-btn
            color="blue"
            tile
            x-large
            icon
            @click="aprovar(item.nomePaciente, item.idEspera, item.matricula)"
          >
            <v-icon>mdi-pencil-circle</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <template
          v-slot:item.delete="{ item }"
        >
          <v-btn
            color="red"
            x-large
            tile
            icon
            @click="abrirModalDeletar(item.nomePaciente, item.idEspera)">
            <v-icon>mdi-delete-circle</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you need a specific item to be editable or could it be any item that happens to be in the first row of the table? The latter is trickier because table sorting would move the items around.

Comment: it will be always the first item of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce a boolean property to your items in the array, let's call it `isFirst` Then you could listen to the event of `current-items` in the data table, which returns the current items in view. And based on that, show the buttons for the first row. So I suggest the following:

```html
<v-data-table @current-items="setFirst" ...... >
```

And the function:

```js
methods: {
  setFirst: function(currItems) {
    // first check that actually exists values
    if (currItems.length) {
      // toggle all to false
      currItems.forEach(x => x.isFirst = false)
      // just set first to true
      currItems[0].isFirst = true;
    }
  }
},
```

and then set an `v-if` to the buttons:

```html
<v-btn v-if="item.isFirst" ....>
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/AJT82/pen/ZEYNeva)**

Answer (score 0):

If your object has an ID and you know what that ID is, you can set a `v-if` statement for your edit and delete buttons to only render when the ID is equal to that value. Something like this:

```
        <template
          v-slot:item.edit="{ item }" >
          <v-btn
            color="blue"
            tile
            v-if="item.id===1"
            x-large
            icon
            @click="aprovar(item.nomePaciente, item.idEspera, item.matricula)"
          >
            <v-icon>mdi-pencil-circle</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <template
          v-slot:item.delete="{ item }"
        >
          <v-btn
            color="red"
            x-large
            tile
            v-if="item.id===1"
            icon
            @click="abrirModalDeletar(item.nomePaciente, item.idEspera)">
            <v-icon>mdi-delete-circle</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
```

If your item doesn't have an ID, when you fetch your data, you can programmatically set a property on the first item and then use the v-if statement on that property.

Something like:

```
fetchData().then(items => {
  if (items.length >= 1) {
    items[0].showEditDelete = true
  } 
})
```

Then your v-if statement will look like `v-if=item.showEditDelete`.